# Dynamic cardview, the click does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I bring the information from Firestore and it does the list well, but at the moment of clicking, the sound is heard but it works.

```
val card_view = CardView(this)
    card_view.id = idCardV
    val layoutParams = LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    layoutParams.bottomMargin = 15
    card_view.layoutParams = layoutParams
    card_view.setContentPadding(6,6,6,6)
    card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
    card_view.radius = 12F
    card_view.cardElevation = 8F
    card_view.maxCardElevation = 12F
    card_view.isClickable = true
    card_view.callOnClick()
    card_view.setOnClickListener { View.OnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "éxito 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
card_view.setOnClickListener { View.OnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "éxito 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } }
```

to

```
card_view.setOnClickListener { 
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "éxito 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Simple mistakes are also complex

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `card_view .focuseable = true` and

```
card_view.setOnClickListener { 
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "éxito 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```